# Can't set extended field to newly created object's Ref Nbr

Tags: acumatica

On the Cash Sales page, I am overriding the release button to create a second Journal Transaction for the record being created that will be adjustments to the cash accounts according to some information on the screen. My process runs fine, successfully creating the new Journal Transaction, but when it goes to set the extended field on the Cash Sales page and then execute the base action of the release button, I get an error message stating:

> Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Fund Batch value GLHW016312 Error: Fund Batch 'GLHW016312' cannot be found in the system.

The code that executes the process is as follows:

```
public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
[PXOverride]
public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
{
    //Journal Transaction uses batch number
    if (Base.CurrentDocument.Current.ExtRefNbr != null && Base.CurrentDocument.Current.ExtRefNbr != string.Empty)
    {
        if (GLSetup.Current.GetExtension<GLSetupExt>().UsrCreateFundEntry == true)
        {
            if (CFBSAdjustments.Select().Count > 0)
            {
                Customer customer = PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<Customer.bAccountID>>>>.Select(Base);
                JournalEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<JournalEntry>();
                Batch batch = graph.BatchModule.Insert();
                batch.Description = "Fund Entry for Cash Sales Reference " + Base.CurrentDocument.Current.RefNbr;
                decimal? debit = 0;
                decimal? credit = 0;
                foreach (CFBSCashSalesAdjustment row in CFBSAdjustments.Select())
                {
                    GLTran tran = graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert();
                    tran.AccountID = row.Account;
                    tran.SubID = row.Subaccount;
                    tran.DebitAmt = row.DebitAmt;
                    tran.CuryDebitAmt = row.DebitAmt;
                    debit += row.DebitAmt;
                    tran.CreditAmt = row.CreditAmt;
                    tran.CuryCreditAmt = row.CreditAmt;
                    credit += row.CreditAmt;
                    tran.RefNbr = row.CashSalesRefNbr;
                    tran.TranDesc = customer.AcctCD + " - " + customer.AcctName;
                    graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(tran);
                }

                batch.CreditTotal = credit;
                batch.CuryCreditTotal = credit;
                batch.DebitTotal = debit;
                batch.CuryDebitTotal = debit;
                batch = graph.BatchModule.Update(batch);
                graph.Actions.PressSave();

                if (GLSetup.Current.GetExtension<GLSetupExt>().UsrAutoRelease == true)
                {
                    graph.BatchModule.Current.Hold = false;
                    graph.release.Press();
                }

                Base.Document.Current.GetExtension<ARRegisterExt>().UsrFundBatch = batch.BatchNbr;
                Base.Actions.PressSave();
            }
        }
    }
    return baseMethod(adapter);
}
```

Upon debugging, I found the error occurs during the return baseMethod(adapter) line.

The odd thing is that if I click OK on the error and click Release again, it'll go through just fine, without any errors, create both records, and set the custom made record to the extension field.

First release, Error:

[image]

Second release, success with added ref nbr link to header:

[image]

As you can see from the pictures, the Batch Number for the Journal Entry when it is successfully created is not the same as the error. It does create the record twice.

For the extended field, I have it set up as a selector with Enabled = false and Allow Edit = true to generate the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user never directly populates your extension field you might just try removing the Selector. Or try specifying `ValidateValue = false` in the Selector.

Comment: The only reason I use the selector is so that I can make a direct link to the record as seen. Is there a different method I can use to create a link to a record besides a selector?

Comment: That did it, thanks a ton! I think I remember needing this for a completely different solution and just forgot about the ValidateValue = false option in the selector.